# How to make buttons change backround on a Simon Says android game

Tags: android

For exercise, I am doing a Simon Say game on android studio.

on an onclick event, went it get to the part of playing the game buttons sequence it looks like that:

```
private void playSequence() {
    for (int i = 0; i < buttonsSequence.size(); i++) {
        buttonsSequence.get(i).setPressed(true);
        buttonsSequence.get(i).invalidate();
        playButton(buttonsSequence.get(i).getId());
        buttonsSequence.get(i).setPressed(false);
        buttonsSequence.get(i).invalidate();
    }
}
```

this is playButton:

```
private void playButton(int buttonId) {
    MediaPlayer mp = null;
    switch (buttonId) {
        case R.id.redButton:
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.redsound);
            break;
        case R.id.blueButton:
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bluesound);
            break;
        case R.id.greenButton:
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.green_sound);
            break;
        case R.id.yellowButton:
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yellow_sound);
            break;
        default:
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "the button I get is wrong. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            return;

    }
    mp.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
    mp.start();
    //// TODO: twice the last to lanes later
    //busy waiting
    while (mp != null && mp.getCurrentPosition() < mp.getDuration() / 6.7) ;
    mp.stop();
}
```

every button has an XML selector like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/lightred"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/red3"></item>
</selector>
```

here the problem: 
the line `buttonsSequence.get(i).invalidate()` need to redraw the background of the button and it doesn't to that and I don't understand why.
the `setPress()` working so what happens here?
the result needs to be for every button:

1. it change background
2. it has been redrawn
3. it sound play
4. it change back to the original background
5. it has been redrawn again
6. continue to the next button

what did I missing here?

**EDIT**

to be more clear, I want the redraw will happen immediately after `invalidate()`.

Comment: You can create Drawables and set them dynamically to each button as background.

Comment: yes. to each button has its own Drawable selector but they are all the same. the only difference is the images to the background: the red button has the red images, the blue button has the blue images ...

Comment: I actually meant to create a Drawable xml like greenbg.xml, redbg.xml etc.. with the color you want it.. and then use it like this:
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greenbg);

Comment: i need the selectors for the part when the player click the buttons.

Comment: I need the selectors for the part when the player clicks the buttons.
i try `btn.setBackgroundResource()` before the selectors and `invalidate()`,
but it give the same result. the id of the drawable change in the button background but the background no redraw it self immediately.